# How I can remove characters between < and > using regex in c#?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string `str="<u>rag</u>"`. Now, i want to get the string `"rag"` only. How can I get it using regex?

My code is here..

I got the output=""

Thanks in advance..

C# code:

```
string input="<u>ragu</u>";
string regex = "(\\<.*\\>)";
string output = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "");
```

Comment: Too many backslashes...

Comment: is it html ? or simple text ?

Comment: @PradipKT It is html..

Comment: its better if you use HTML AGILITY PACK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `regex` for parsing html is not recommended

`regex` is used for regularly occurring patterns.`html` is not regular with it's format(except `xhtml`).For example `html` files are valid even if you **don't** have a `closing tag`!This could break your code.

Use an html parser like [htmlagilitypack](http://html-agility-pack.net/?z=codeplex)

---

**WARNING** {Don't try this in your code}

To solve your regex problem!

`<.*>` replaces `<` followed by 0 to many characters(i.e `u>rag</u`) till **last** >

You should replace it with this regex

```
<.*?>
```

`.*` is **greedy** i.e it would eat as many characters as it matches

`.*?` is **lazy** i.e it would eat as less characters as possible

Answer (score 9):

```
const string HTML_TAG_PATTERN = "<.*?>";
Regex.Replace (str, HTML_TAG_PATTERN, string.Empty);
```

Comment: +1 for being the first to come up with this simple non-greedy expression.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can:

```
   string input = "<u>ragu</u>";
    string regex = "(\\<[/]?[a-z]\\>)";
    string output = Regex.Replace(input, regex, "");
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use regex for that.

```
string input = "<u>rag</u>".Replace("<u>", "").Replace("</u>", "");
Console.WriteLine(input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code was almost correct, a small modification makes it work:

```
 string input = "<u>ragu</u>";
 string regex = @"<.*?\>";
 string output = Regex.Replace(input, regex, string.empty);
```

Output is 'ragu'.

**EDIT**: this solution may not be the best. Interesting remark from user the-land-of-devils-srilanka: do not use regex to parse HTML. Indeed, see also [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).